# Internet connection blocked after install (Win10)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-installer, windows-10

I don't really now where to put this question, so i'll try it here.

I got a problem installing my .Net 4.5 winforms application using the msi setup project (installshield).

After installation of the application, i can connect to the internet to activate my application (launch.exe, started from the msi). Then when launch.exe starts the application itself (app.exe) this one can not connect to the internet.

When i don't restart the PC. Close the application and try to restart using launch.exe, also launch.exe can't connect.

When i do a restart of the machine, and restart launch.exe (and this again starts app.exe) they both are able to connect to the internet.

I also tried to inspect the traffic with Fiddler using Fiddler as the proxy-server (127.0.0.1:8888). When i use Fiddler, the connection suddenly isn't blocked anymore. Probably due to the fact fiddler is no generating the traffic to the internet, but i'm not sure about that.

Windows firewall is disabled (but can't disable virus scanner due to policy). The problem only occurs on windows 10 machines and not on windows 7 machines. Both having the same version of Bitdefender installed.

FYI: Virusscanner is Bitdefender Endpoint Security. I know this has a firewall included.

Could this have anything to do with UAC?

```cs
    LicentieService.LicentieServiceClient licentieService = new LicentieService.LicentieServiceClient();

    ProxyData pd = ProxyData.Instance;
    if (pd.UseProxy)
    {
      System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = pd.Proxy;

      var endpoint = licentieService.Endpoint.Binding as System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding;
      if (endpoint != null && !endpoint.UseDefaultWebProxy) { endpoint.UseDefaultWebProxy = true; }
    }
    else
    {
      System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
    }

    var result = licentieService.CallToSomeXMLSoapFunction();
```

Comment: "i can connect to the internet to activate my application" Unless you share the code that does this, it's unlikely that you'll get any help.

Comment: I'm not allowed to share the exact code. But it's nothing special. I just connect to a web-service (wcf). Before connection can of course set the proxy-server to use (in case of the Fiddler Connections)

DefaultProxy = false;
...